# Is it possible to customize size of listview item for simple_list_item1

Tags: java, android, listview

Is it possible to change the list item's height and text size for the listview that used as simple_list_item1? Any help is really appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: nope you have to create custom list item then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the List Item's height and test size if you are using **simple_list_item1**.
You should use ListView custom adapter and create XML layout for your List Item.

see this..

http://sujitdroid.blogspot.com/